# Where is the jquery and jquery_ujs being loaded from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application.js file has the following:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

I do not have jquery anywhere in my assets folder or in my vendor/assets folder.

My gemfile does have:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Where are the files though?

Answer (score 3):

The jquery-rails gem contains the jquery and jquery_ujs files. After the gem is installed, call

```
gem which jquery-rails
```

This gives you the path where your gem is located. under that folder search for jquery.js. This is the jquery java script that is loaded.